# jQuery trigger on event when other script is loaded / element from other script is created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the text inside a dynamically generated p element after this element is from another script.

The adobe edge script creates two p elements inside #Stage. I need to change the text inside these p elements after they are created.

I actually can change the text with the on.("click") event but i need to fire this event as soon as the p elements are genereated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="edge_includes/edge.6.0.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
        <div id="Stage">

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( "#Stage" ).on( "click", "p", function() {
                $("#Stage p").text("New Content");
            });
        </script>


    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: You could observe your DOM and recat to changes. For this you can use MutationObserver


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: You can refer to this jQuery library - http://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```js
 $(function(){
 $("<p></p>").appendTo($("#Stage"));
 $("<p></p>").appendTo($("#Stage"));
 $("<p></p>").appendTo($("#Stage"));
});

$("#Stage p").livequery(function () {
 $("#Stage p").text("New Content");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/livequery/1.1.1/jquery.livequery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Stage"></div>
```

Comment: The p tag is already added to the page by the edge.6.0.0.min.js script. I tried to use your script and your code but the livequery event is not firing.

Comment: You can run the code snipped in my response above. When you click on the button, a new p tag is added to the "stage" dive. The livequery will then automatically update the text of p tage.

Comment: The p tag i need to change is genereted in the edge script on page load. I need to change this p tag as soon as the page load is finished. But i cant because its dynamically generated.

Comment: @Peesen87 Updated code. As you can see in page onload, I dynamically add 3 `p` tags (in your case it will be done by edge script). As soon as the `p` tags are added to "stage" div, livequery will update the text of `p` tag.